# Is it possible to add only HashCode method in lombok?

Tags: lombok

I want to implement my own `equals(Object o)` method so I want to add only `hashCode()` using lombok. But I don't see such an option. Is there a workaround for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, in Lombok, there isn't. You could use `java.util.Objects.hash()` method, though.

BTW. Why do you want such behavior? And are you aware of the recently added Lombok functionality that lets you apply `@EqualsAndHashCode` with respect to methods (and not only fields): https://projectlombok.org/features/EqualsAndHashCode (look for `@EqualsAndHashCode.Include`).

Answer (score 0):

Technically, you could use `@Tolerate`, but I wouldn't recommend that.

Comment: AFAIK you can't as Lombok would generate *both* methods which is obviously wrong, see [this comment of mine](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/pull/52#issue-20090660).